# Is there a word for thinking of something as a disease?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am look for a word meaning to think of something as a disease such as if a speakers says:

> James's influence is corrupting the area, and it spreads from person to person like an influenza.

Is there a verb that describes the act of thinking of Jame's influence as a form of ***disease*** in particular, in similar vein as to otherize, to feminize or to animalize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a word "pathologise". If, for example, I try to explain someone's criminal behaviour in terms of the person's psychological state, and their deep-seated emotional needs, then I am "pathologising" behaviour that the authorities may look upon in a legal or moral way.

Americans would presumably spell it with a Z.

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that indeed was what I had been looking for.  Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 2):

James’s influence is ***[contagious:](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/contagious)***

> (of an emotion, feeling, or attitude) likely to spread to and affect others.

(Lexico)

Comment: Actual, his influence has *gone viral*.

Comment: That's not what the question asked.